# Axios cancellation is not working in axios client file - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have created a common axios request file for API services, a common function `getRequest(URL)` is getting called where it require.

What i want to achieve is, previous request should be cancelled whenever the new request is getting called/triggered.

Here is what i have tried but its not working as expected.

```js
// My component Users.js
async function getUsers(url) {
    try {
        const response = await getRequest(url);
        // further process with the response
    } catch (error){
        // handling error here
    }
}

useEffect( ()=>{
    // URL is getting form endpoints constnats
    getUsers(URL);
},[]);
// --------------- end of my component ---------------
```

```js
//axiosClient.js
import axios from 'axios';
import { BASEURL } from '../config/endpoints';
import { getToken } from '../Auth';

const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;

export function getRequest(URL, payload={}, headers={}) {
    return apiRequest(URL, payload, "get", headers);
}

export async function apiRequest(endPoint, data, method, headers, requestOptions = {}) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const token = getToken();
      const headers = {
        Accept: 'application/json',
      };
      
      if (data instanceof FormData) {
        headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
      } else {
        headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
      }
  
      if (token) {
        headers['access_token'] = token;
      }
  
      axios({
        method: method,
        url: endPoint,
        headers:headers,
        data: data,
        cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {return c;})
      }).then((result) => { return resolve(result); }).catch((error) => {return reject(error);});
      return false;
    });
  }
// --------------- end of axios client ----------------
```

Comment: How are you verifying that it is not working?

Comment: I am checking in browser network request. whenever new api call the old remain in pending instead of cancel.

Comment: I thought that might be it. There's no way to cancel the network request after it's been made. All you can really do is ignore the response

Comment: I think Axios has feature to cancel the request. https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the solutions.

```js
//axiosClient.js

import axios from 'axios';
import { BASEURL } from '../config/endpoints';
import { getToken } from '../Auth';

const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
let cancel;

export function getRequest(URL, payload={}, headers={}) {
    return apiRequest(URL, payload, "get", headers);
}

export async function apiRequest(endPoint, data, method, headers, requestOptions = {}) {
    if (cancel !== undefined) cancel();

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const token = getToken();
      const headers = {
        Accept: 'application/json',
      };
      
      if (data instanceof FormData) {
        headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
      } else {
        headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
      }
  
      if (token) {
        headers['access_token'] = token;
      }
  
      axios({
        method: method,
        url: endPoint,
        headers:headers,
        data: data,
        cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {return c;})
      }).then((result) => { return resolve(result); }).catch((error) => {return reject(error);});
      return false;
    });
  }
// --------------- end of axios client ----------------
```